# Distinguish Scala-3 Enum and Sealed Traits

Tags: scala, enums, scala-macros, scala-3

Is it possible to distinguish Scala-3 enums and sealed traits using Mirrors or even Macros?

```
transparent inline def isScalaEnum[A]: Boolean = ${ isScalaEnumImpl[A] }
private def isScalaEnumImpl[A: Type](using q: Quotes): Expr[Boolean] = ???
```

For example, how do you implement the above macro?

```
sealed trait T
case class A(x: Int) extends T
case class B(x: String) extends T

enum Color(val rgb: Int):
  case Red   extends Color(1)
  case Green extends Color(2)

isScalaEnum[T]     should be false
isScalaEnum[Color] should be true
```

Comment: Did you try things that didn't work?

Comment: I did not find any distinguishing factor.

Comment: Maybe checking against `scala.reflect.Enum` which is the base trait of all enums in Scala3? That wouldn't even involve `Quotes` or `Type`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `<:<` and `NotGiven`:

- `<:< reflect.Enum` for checking whether your type is subclass of `scala.reflect.Enum` (which is true only for Scala 3 `enum`s)
- `NotGiven` for translating the absence of `<:<`-evidence into a `false`

Here is how it can be implemented:

```
import scala.util.NotGiven

case class IsEnum[X](value: Boolean)
given isEnum[X](using X <:< reflect.Enum): IsEnum[X] = IsEnum(true)
given isNotEnum[X](using NotGiven[X <:< reflect.Enum]): IsEnum[X] = IsEnum(false)
inline def isScalaEnum[X](using inline ev: IsEnum[X]): Boolean = ev.value
```

Here is how it can be used:

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar

sealed trait NotFoo

@main def demo(): Unit =
  println(isScalaEnum[Foo])         // true
  println(isScalaEnum[NotFoo])      // false
```

## Update

If you want to have more precise type information at compile time, just transparently inline all the things:

```
import scala.util.NotGiven
case class IsEnum[X](value: Boolean)
transparent inline given isEnum[X](using X <:< reflect.Enum): IsEnum[X] =
  IsEnum(true)
transparent inline given isNotEnum[X](using NotGiven[X <:< reflect.Enum]): IsEnum[X] =
  IsEnum(false)
transparent inline def isScalaEnum[X](using inline ev: IsEnum[X]): ev.value.type =
  ev.value
```

It then behaves similarly to the test cases that you've mentioned in your own answer, with `Null` and `Nothing` being notable exceptions:

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar

enum FooS(x:String):
  case Bar extends FooS("str")

sealed trait NotFoo
inline val a: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo]
inline val b: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo.Bar.type]
inline val c: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS]
inline val d: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS.Bar.type]
inline val e: false = isScalaEnum[NotFoo]
inline val f: false = isScalaEnum[Int]
inline val g: false = isScalaEnum[String]
inline val x: true = isScalaEnum[Null]
inline val y: true = isScalaEnum[Nothing]
```

Comment: it is a really nice solution. But since I write the enum at compile-time, I feel like `isScalaEnum` should give me an answer at compile-time too. However, I could not improve your solution to accept `inline val a = isScalaEnum[Foo]`.

Comment: @Koosha Implicits are resolved at compile time already. This solution doesn't have any performance penalty

Comment: @Koosha Re: "should give me an answer at compile-time too" - updated; Making everything transparently inlined allows the compiler to infer the exact type of the inlined expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Andrey Tyukin and @Gaël J, here is a simpler version.

```
transparent inline def isScalaEnum[X]: Boolean = inline compiletime.erasedValue[X] match
  case _: Null         => false // Return false for Null, regardless of whether explicit-nulls are enabled.
  case _: Nothing      => false // I prefer false for Nothing
  case _: reflect.Enum => true
  case _               => false
```

Here are some tests:

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar

enum FooS(x:String):
  case Bar extends FooS("str")

sealed trait NotFoo
inline val a: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo]
inline val b: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo.Bar.type]
inline val c: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS]
inline val d: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS.Bar.type]
inline val e: false = isScalaEnum[NotFoo]
inline val f: false = isScalaEnum[Int]
inline val g: false = isScalaEnum[String]
inline val x: false = isScalaEnum[Null]
inline val y: false = isScalaEnum[Nothing]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gaël J's comment, here is what I came up with. Unfortunately, it uses Macro, but a simple one.

In one file:

```
import scala.quoted.*

transparent inline def isScalaEnum[A]: Boolean =
  ${ isScalaEnumImpl[A] }

private def isScalaEnumImpl[A: Type](using q: Quotes): Expr[Boolean] =
  import q.reflect.*
  TypeRepr.of[A].asType match
    case '[Null]         => Expr(false) // Return false for Null, regardless of whether explicit-nulls are enabled.
    case '[Nothing]      => Expr(false) // I prefer false for Nothing
    case '[reflect.Enum] => Expr(true)
    case _               => Expr(false)
```

Here are my test:

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar

enum FooS(x:String):
  case Bar extends FooS("str")

sealed trait NotFoo

@main
def demo(): Unit =
  inline val a: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo]
  inline val b: true  = isScalaEnum[Foo.Bar.type]
  inline val c: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS]
  inline val d: true  = isScalaEnum[FooS.Bar.type]
  inline val e: false = isScalaEnum[NotFoo]
  inline val f: false = isScalaEnum[Int]
  inline val g: false = isScalaEnum[Null]
  inline val h: false = isScalaEnum[Nothing]
```

Please let me know if you think there is an easier/better solution, or there is something wrong with what I provided here.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Andrey Tyukin comments/answers, I changed the macro to treat `Null` and `Nothing` explicitly.